# Wordpress - How can i show subpages, but not the parent of those subpage?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the latest version of Wordpress 3.3.2.  I have several pages setup that have several subpages to them. The parent pages act as categories or main sections of the website.

Here is my basic structure:

```
Parent_Page
 - Subpage_1
   -- Child_of_1
   -- Child_of_1
   -- Child_of_1
 - Subpage_2
   -- Child of_2
```

And so on...So what i want to do is only out the "child" pages and not the subpages or the parent page.

This will give me a list of all pages inside of all of my main section.

Currently  i am using get_pages, but it appears to be a little buggy.  When i exclude a few pages its starts taking away the child pages along with the parent pages.

```
 $storeparent = 18;
 $shopargs = array(
'depth'        => -1,
'child_of' => $storeparent,
'title_li'     => __(''),
'sort_column'  => 'menu_order',
'post_status'  => 'publish',
'link_before'  => '',
'link_after'   => '',
'echo' => 1,
'exclude' => '149,151'
 );
```

Where  i am excluding pages, i can add a few and it works, but the once i hit a certain page ID it starts removing the child pages as well.  A little confusing because i am not telling it to remove the child pages.

The pages i am excluding there now are pages that are on the same level as the "Parent_Page".

Do i have to order the pages i want to exclude in numerical order?

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show what is `$storeparent`

Answer (score 0):

Try change  the depth to 2.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: hmm i had thought i had tried that, but I'll try that again.  $storeparent variable is the ID of Parent_Page.  That way i can grab all of the pages under that main page and ignore the rest of the pages i've added.

Comment: yeah that didn't work. I'm trying to only output the 3rd tier pages and i don't want to output any of the parent categories.  Doesnt seem to be that easy.

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested I found what I think to be an interesting solution to this problem. I found a plugin called tags2pages. As you can imagine, this plugin allows you to add tags to pages in exactly the same way as a post.  I tagged my 3rd-tier pages with a special and wrote a query using WP_Query to output only those pages.  Works very well and gives me some added flexibility.  What i would love to see wordpress do is add categories and tags to pages.